# Tomar la Id de un array en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-spinner

Hola tengo este código

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private EditText Number1 , Number2;
        private Spinner Operations;
        private TextView Result;
        private Resources Resources;

        private ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter;
        private String[] Options;
        private int Total;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

             Result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.LblResult);

             Operations = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerOperations);

             Number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtNumberOne);
             Number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtNumberTwo);

             Resources = this.getResources();

             Options = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.operations);
             Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,Options);
             Operations.setAdapter(Adapter);
        }

        public void showTotal(View v){
            Result.setText("");
            String OperationSelected;
            OperationSelected = Operations.getSelectedItem().toString();
            int N1 = Integer.parseInt(Number1.getText().toString());
            int N2 = Integer.parseInt(Number2.getText().toString());
            Total = Methods.Calculate(N1,N2,OperationSelected);
            Result.setText(""+Total);
        }
    }
```

Pero en vez de tomar los valores del array, quiero que tome el id del array o la posicion, es decir, Array[0].

Intente con

```
private int[] Options;
Options = this.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.operations);
```

Pero en

```
Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,Options);
```

Me aparece error

**Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(com.example.calculator.MainActivity,int,int[])'**

Answer (score 0):

Has lo siguiente

```
Operations.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //donde parent es el adapter y position la posición o indice seleccionado, guarda el valor position en una variable global y luego solo la asignas en donde la necesitas
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: En que parte la coloco?

Comment: Puedes colocarlo al final del oncreate, no es lo mejor pero te servira para empezar, después puedes implementar la interfaz en la clase y sobreescribir el metodo o crear otra clase donde implementes la interfaz y manejes toda la logica ahi para tener codigo mas limpio.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero usar un método para convertir el array de int[] a String[] :

```
private String[] convierteArrayIntToString(int[] intArray){

    Arrays.sort(intArray);
    return Arrays.toString(intArray).split("[\\[\\]]")[1].split(", ");

}
```

y usarlo al definir tu adapter para que reciba los valores como tipo String en lugar de Int:

```
Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, convierteArrayIntToString(Options));
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione con este código

```
OperationSelected = Operations.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Ya con esto puedo saber la posición